# Using Promise for a function that is not called by JavaScript

Tags: javascript, google-signin

I am using Google Sign-In and have the following problem:

`sessionStorage.getItem('userEntity')` returns `null` when I close the browser and open it again. It does not return null if I just reload the page.

The session will be set in this function:

```
// Signing in
function onSignIn(googleUser) {
    var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();

    // Store the entity object in sessionStorage where it will be accessible from all pages
    let userEntity = {};
    userEntity.id = profile.getId();
    userEntity.name = profile.getName();
    userEntity.img = profile.getImageUrl();
    userEntity.email = profile.getImageUrl();
    sessionStorage.setItem('userEntity',JSON.stringify(userEntity));

    userIsLoggedOut.style.display = 'none';
    userIsLoggedIn.style.display = 'flex';
    document.querySelector('.user-img').setAttribute('src', userEntity.img);
}
```

I do not run this function in JavaScript. The following HTML will make it run:

```
<div class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn"></div>
```

Even if I put `console.log(sessionStorage.getItem('userEntity'))` after the function or on the bottom of my JavaScript, it still returns null.

I guess a solution would be using Promise but how can I use it if I don't run the function `onSignIn()` in JavaScript?

Comment: I think you should be using local storage if you want data to persist between browser restarts. This is explained in the documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage

Comment: Firstly, `onSignIn` is javascript, therefore it i**is** "run in javascript". But you're absolutely incorrect in thinking that Promises would help make "sessionStorage" persist over browser restarts, because, well, nothing will

Comment: As the comment from Jake said, you might want to use Local Storage instead of Session Storage. If you actually need Session Storage, are you sure the setItem method is being called? Have you debugged your onSignIn method? An easy way to debug it is just put `debugger;` in your javascript, and that should cause a breakpoint to be hit

Comment: @JakeHolzinger thank you! localStorage was definitely the solution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data stored in SessionStorage are deleted when you close the tab or the browser, more details below:
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_sessionstorage.asp

You can use localStorage instead to keep the data in the browser even if you close the tab or the browser, so change the following line:

```
sessionStorage.setItem('userEntity',JSON.stringify(userEntity));
```

by

```
localStorage.setItem('userEntity',JSON.stringify(userEntity));
```

But you have to take care about the security of the informations stored in the localStorage, you can deal with secure cookies if you need to store secure data client side.

Answer (score 1):

You can copy item from sessionStorage to localStorage:

```
localStorage.setItem('userEntity', sessionStorage.getItem('userEntity'));
```

It will be persistent, so you can use it anytime:

```
localStorage.getItem('userEntity');
```